# Why the newline char are removed by concat

Tags: tcl

I have this code:

```
set l [concat a b c "\r\n"]
puts "[llength $l]:$l"
```

I like to add "\r\n" as the last element of the list, but it seems it is removed:

```
>tclsh try.tcl
3:a b c
```

Any reason of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `\r` (carriage return) and `\n` (newline) are whitespace characters according to Tcl's rules, so the whitespace character stripping rules of `concat` remove them from leading and trailing positions. As [the documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/concat.htm) says (emphasis mine):

> This command joins each of its arguments together with spaces ***after trimming leading and trailing white-space from each*** of them.

If you want that extra two-character EOL-sequence on the end of your list where it won't affect the values in the list, just `append` it afterwards:

```
set l [concat a b c]
append l "\r\n"
puts "$l:[llength $l]"
```

On the other hand, if you want that string as a list element, `lappend` it as that will automatically add all the quoting required. Also bear in mind that `concat` isn't a *true* list concatenation operation (it does complicated string operations); the true list concatenation is:

```
set concatenated [list {*}$listA {*}$listB]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tcl, list elements are separated by spaces or  newlines. So having newline alone doesn't mandate it to be separate element. You should nest the list element and then it will work.

```
% set l [concat a b c [list "\r\n"]]   
a b c {                                
}                                      
% puts "[llength $l]:$l"               
4:a b c {                              
}                                      
%
```

Answer (score 0):

The `concat` command returns a string which is a prettified list with a single space between elements and no whitespace before the first element or after the last.

What you're looking for is the `list` command:

```
% set l [list a b c "\r\n"]
a b c {
}
% puts [llength $l]:$l
4:a b c {
}
```

Documentation:
[concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm)